# In app purchase in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

I'm using the IAP feature of Windows Phone 8, it's working fine. I have uploaded a `.xap` file for Beta testing, while I'm testing it, it shows me two buttons, <kbd>**Install**</kbd> and <kbd>**Cancel**</kbd>, I need to change the content of the <kbd>**Install**</kbd> button to <kbd>**Purchase**</kbd>, I don't know how to do that, does anyone know how to change that?
I mean how to customize purchase dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Are these buttons specific to your app? In the general purchase experience (this is common across WP platform and can't be changed) you won't see them, only "Buy" (if it is paid) or "Free" (if it is free IAP or beta) and "Cancel" button to cancel the operation... see the sample IAP screen here http://cdn.asia.cnet.com/story_media/62216832/iap.jpg

As you mentioned in the question that this is a beta app, all IAP purchases are free in beta application and also in emulator.

Comment: So While we submit app in public store it would be changed automatically into Buy or Install.

Comment: you can verify the same without publishing into store...if you have dev unlocked phone, you can deploy the app onto phone and test the IAP scenarios..

Comment: @Mahender & Mohit  Is the In-App Purchase in windows phone 8 is same as Windows Store apps(Coding are all same)?
and If its same means In Dashboard of Windows Store apps we provide feature name to identify the particular product for purchase. But in windows phone 8 Dashboard there is nothing to be like that(I didn't even find the Feature name to be asked in windows phone 8 Dashboard)

Help to sort out this????